# Do we need ['$scope'] or not

Tags: angularjs

In this example (http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_scope), it uses

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Volvo";
});
```

But, if I add ['$scope'], it still works.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Volvo";
}]);
</script>
```

I see both ways when people write that kind of code, any difference? Do I need to add ['$scope', ] or not? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the array notation protects the string "$scope" from minification. there are build tools that will take care of adding the array notation, so, no, *you* don't have to do it. but if the code will be minified, then it has to be performed.